# Как перехватить исключение любого типа в C#

Tags: c#, исключения

Как перехватить исключение любого типа в C#?

Comment: Советую как можно реже употреблять ловлю исключений.
Лучше сразу все учитывать, хотя, без них порой не обойтись (:

Comment: Pokémon Exception Handling детектед)

Comment: @Сергей если пишется пользовательское приложение, то на самом верхнем уровне без этого никак ваще-то.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Необходимо использовать следующую схему кода

```
 try {
        // Блок кода, где генерируется исключение
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Выполняем обработку исключительной ситуации
    }
```

Comment: catch (Exception e) поймает исключения только базового типа Exception!

Comment: Вы что? С каких это пор? Ловиться будут исключения типа Exception и все его потомки.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m я не написал "производные от" ну и далее по тексту "базового типа Exception". Кому надо тот понял.

Comment: А разве могут быть исключения не наследующие Exception? Я не знаток C#, но должен быть какой-то базовый, от которого идут ВСЕ ошибки (например, в Java он называется Throwable). Именно такой базовый и надо ловить.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m нет не обязаны. Есть одно правило - все классы порождаются от Object. Тип исключения просто такой же новый тип - как хочешь так и создавай.

Comment: IAZ, а зачем? тоже не знаток шарпа, но класс базовый исключений для того и нужен, чтобы ловить все и вся

Comment: @uramer239 видимо по тому, что нельзя придумать единый вид исключения, который устроит всех и во всех случаях. Иногда нужно много информации, а иногда только факт того, что исключение произошло. Исключение может произойти от нехватки памяти, а объекта исключения может быть нужно метр памяти, и что в этом случае делать? И заметьте - это не зависит от языка!

Comment: В этом случае достаточно задампить в лог сообщение об ошибке, которое внутри исключения. А если исключения нет, то получается, что неизвестно что случилось. Никакой диагностики.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m вы не поняли - это был риторический вопрос. В описанном мною случае делать ничего не получиться - поскольку памяти не хватит для создания исключения. Прога рухнет не сумев обработать исключение.

Comment: Я не знаю что в C#, но в Java такое никогда не случается: OutOfMemoryError всегда есть.. ну уверен, за счёт чего это достигается. Думаю, в C# эта проблема тоже как-то решена.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m не кажется ли вам что вы ушли уже далеко от темы?

Answer (score 8):

```
try {
}
catch {
    // Выполняем обработку исключительной ситуации
}
```

Comment: Выполнить обработку? И что же мы можем тут полезного предпринять, не имея сведений об ошибке?

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, это уже другой вопрос, задайте его в отдельной ветке. Тем не менее на данный вопрос именно этот правильный.

Answer (score 2):

В коде, который использует только c#-библиотеки, достаточно ловить `Exception`. В C# все исключения отнаследованы от `Exception`.

```
try
{
..
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
..
}
```

В коде, который использует библиотеки на других языках, желательно ловить исключения без указания типа. Другие языки могут кидать исключения с типами, отличными от `Exception`.

```
try
{
..
}
catch
{
..
}
```

Комбинированный вариант использования перехватывает все исключения и сохраняет информацию для C#-исключений.

```
try
{
..
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
..
}
catch
{
..
}
```

Comment: Если не секрет, то о каких других языках речь?

Comment: @PavelMayorov C++/Cli

Comment: Насколько я знаю, исключения C++ в cl - это вполне себе исключения SEH, а последние ловятся дотнетом как SEHException. Или в C++/Cli можно взять и System::String^ как исключение кинуть?

Comment: В C++/Cli в исключении можно кинуть любой тип: int, System::String^ и т.д.

Comment: Только что проверил. Да, System::String кинуть можно - но в код на C# в итоге прилетит [RuntimeWrappedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimewrappedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо! Еще в .net 2.0 поведение поменялось, и framework начал оборачивать всё в Exception.