# Информация об исключении

Tags: c#

Иногда, в приложении необходимо выполнить [перехват всех исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137/). В С# имеет место следующая конструкция:

```
try {
}
catch {
    // Выполняем обработку исключительной ситуации
}
```

Каким образом в данном случае получить информацию об обрабатываемом исключении?

Comment: Эта конструкция почи не имеет смысла. Единственное, что она может сделать, это помочь проигнорировать ошибку. При этом, никакой отладочной информации вы не сможете получить. Таким образом, это вредная конструкция. Лучше всего ловить базовый класс исключений.

Comment: упорство @cy6erGn0m с которым Вы пытаетесь "доказать" что данная конструкция не применима достойно другого приложения.

Comment: Разве я не привёл веских аргументов? Вам одно говорят, а вы всё C++ примешиваете в каких-то неествественных кейзах.

Comment: Как не понятно: в C# не может возникнуть никаких исключений, которые взялись неведомо откуда и имеющие неведомо какой тип. Это вам не C. Поэтому отлов базового исключения является естественным решением, потому что это то же самое, только с информацией об ошибке и вы можете что-то предпринять.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m я видимо пропустил аргументы. Отсутствие отладочной информации - вот это аргумент? Тогда хотя бы написали "информации об исключении", поскольку к отладочной информации исключение не имеет отношения.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m а как же пользовательские исключения? Которые не обязаны наследоваться от Exception.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m а как же отображение общего (для всего приложения) сообщения об ошибке (и возможно отправки его на свой сервер - для информации) с последующим закрытием программы? Еще нужны примеры когда применять такой отлов исключений?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак, мы не получаем никакой информации о отловленном исключении.
Информацию можно получить только так:

```
try{
}
catch(Exception ex){
    // обработка исключения ex
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Данная конструкция (и аналогичная в C++ catch(...) ) предназначена для отлова всех исключений, в тех случаях когда недопустимо выбрасывать во вне какое либо исключение (в драйверах например или в конструкторах - для C++).

Comment: Ой, не приплетайте только отлов SEH и т.п. вещей.. это всё жутко непеносимо.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m уже не первый раз вижу, что Вы читать не умеете - где я говорил про SEH? Для отлова таких исключений требуются совсем другие инструкции.

Comment: Я подумал, что вы их имеете в виду про "в тех случаях когда недопустимо выбрасывать во вне какое либо исключение". Потому что все остальные исключения нет смысла ловить таким обезличенным способом.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m пример когда нужно перехватывать исключения я уже написал "...или в конструкторах - для C++". Для шарпа затрудняюсь сказать наверняка, но возможно что так же.